# string with space as thousand separator to float Python Pandas can not replace ' ' with ''

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to remove space as thousands separator from pandas series.

```
print(newframe['ALV 0 %'].head())
newframe['ALV 0 %'] = newframe['ALV 0 %'].str.replace(',','.')
newframe['ALV 0 %'] = newframe['ALV 0 %'].str.replace(' ','')
print('alv 0 head xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
print(newframe['ALV 0 %'].head())
```

This is what I get

```
2    1 177,44
3    1 032,06
4    1 239,09
5      784,86
6      936,27
Name: ALV 0 %, dtype: object
alv 0 head xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2    1 177.44
3    1 032.06
4    1 239.09
5      784.86
6      936.27
Name: ALV 0 %, dtype: object
```

Why doesn't this remove spaces?
Help appreciated.